# Fall-back fonts for JavaScript context.font

Tags: javascript, css, font-family

Is there any way I can have multiple fall-back fonts for JavaScript context.font?

> *a fall-back font is a font that the browser
>
> 'falls back' to if the current one isn't supported*

For example:

```
ctx.font = '20px arial'
ctx.fillText('Hello World!', 100, 100)
```

Let's say that **arial** wasn't supported. How would I make the computer *fall back* to **tahoma** and then **verdana**?

I kind of understand how **CSS** works: `font-family: arial, tahoma, verdana`

... But does **context.font** do the same thing as **CSS**?
Can I just write this: `ctx.font = '20px arial, tahoma, verdana'`? Or do I need to do something else for it to work?

Comment: You could had tested this easily, but yes, [the standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#dom-context-2d-font-dev) says: "_The syntax is the same as for the CSS 'font' property_".

Comment: @Teemu : thank you for the link, that answers my question. But just for future - how do I test for this kind of thing? Would I have to install different browsers and see if the font works or not?

Comment: It would be good to have a couple of major browsers, including mobile browsers. Usually you'll check [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/font). Take also a look at https://caniuse.com/